# How can I select columns and rows with variable in R?

Tags: r

I have an object `currency` I would like to select one column and the rows equal to 1 with the variable `Pair`.

```
>currency
           EURUSD EURUSDi USDJPY USDJPYi GBPUSD GBPUSDi AUDUSD AUDUSDi XAUUSD XAUUSDi zeroes
2000-07-16      0       0      0       0      0       1      0       0      0       0      0
2000-07-23      0       0      0       0      0       1      0       0      0       0      0
2000-07-30      0       0      0       0      0       1      0       0      0       0      0
2000-08-06      0       0      0       0      0       0      0       0      0       1      0
2000-08-13      0       1      0       0      0       0      0       0      0       0      0
```

From the console I can do it with subset like this :

```
> subset(currency$GBPUSDi, GBPUSDi == 1)
           GBPUSDi
2000-07-16       1
2000-07-23       1
2000-07-30       1
2000-08-06       1
2000-08-13       1
2000-08-20       1
```

But as soon as it is passed in a script with variable `Pair` it fails. I've searched for hours in the documentation and I'm having a headache trying to figure out what is wrong.

Please find the different command I've try :

```
subset (currency$Pair, Pair == 1)
subset (currency, Pair = 1, select = Pair)
weights$Cur[currency$Pair = 1]
```

The one that works is `currency[,c(Pair)]` but it only select column, how can I complete with row selection of `Pair` = 1 ?

`currency[,c(Pair)][Pair = 1]` and `subset (currency[,c(Pair)], Pair = 1)` with `=` or `==` doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide an example dataset and expected result

Comment: `currency[currency$Pair == 1,]`

Comment: Sorry, I added an example.
@Roland it doesn't work because it returns only columns's name `EURUSD EURUSDi USDJPY USDJPYi GBPUSD GBPUSDi AUDUSD AUDUSDi XAUUSD XAUUSDi zeroes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currency$Pair[currency$Pair == 1]` should work (`$Pair` select column `Pair` and `[currency$Pair == 1]` select values equal to 1). It looks like it don't work in your case, because `currency` don't contain variable `Pair`.

If `currency` is not a dataframe but matrix, you can try
`currency[currency[, c("Pair")] == 1, c("Pair")]`

Comment: I have checked with `print(currency)` in the loop and it returns the data, `print(Pair)` also returns the columns name (i.e. EURUSD, EURUSDi, etc), but for some reason `print(currency$Pair)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Many thanks,  `currency` is an xts object (.ie. matrix ?) and it works with `currency[currency[, c(Pair)] == 1, c(Pair)]` (without the "")